# Wrap & Unwrap RSA Private key using PKCS#11

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, private-key, pkcs#11

I have RSA Priavte Key in HSM and i need to copy (Wrap & Unwrap) it to security token using PKCS#11 interface & C#

How to Wrap & Unwrap RSA Private Key using PKCS#11 interface?

I need to know the steps. I know that i have to use symmetric key (AES) with CBC mode. But I need to know the other attributes for the secret key.

**Update:**

I created AES key 'CBC' and gave it the attributes to Wrap & Unwrap & Encrypt & Decrypt. And wrapped the the RSA private key but failed in the unwrap process with error **CKR WRAPPED KEY INVALID**

Comment: Are you sure that the private key is exportable at all from that HSM? Usually they are not.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that it is exportable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is that you need to wrap RSA keys by Secret key AES with **ECB** mechanism not CBC.